# How can I add $post content in a rewrite rule?

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

I want to be able to replace the slug of my custom post type with the value from the post's meta key.

Can I pass $post information into a function that I can use to edit rewrite rules?

SO instead of having a post URL as /procedure/facelift/, I want it to be like:

`get_post(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'slug', true))->post_name.'/facelift/`

Answer (score 0):

check this plugin,

- [Custom Fields Permalink Redux](https://github.com/athlan/wordpress-custom-fields-permalink-plugin)

[image]

OR You may use code,

```
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'my_post_type_link', 10, 3);
function my_post_type_link($permalink, $post, $leavename) {

if  ($post->post_type == 'my-post-type') {
    $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_my-post-meta', true);
    if (isset($meta) && !empty($meta)) 
        $permalink = home_url( "my-friendly-url/" . $meta . "/" . $post->post_name . "/");
}
return $permalink;

}

add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', 'my_rewrite_rules_array');
function my_rewrite_rules_array($rules) {
$rules = array('my-friendly-url/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=my-post-type&name=$matches[2]&meta=$matches[1]') + $rules;
return $rules;
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

For more information,

- [Wordpres Custom Fields Permalink Plugin](http://athlan.pl/wordpres-custom-fields-permalink-plugin/)
- [WordPress permalink for custom post type based on post meta](https://gist.github.com/petenelson/4020471)

Comment: This doesn't answer my question at all, please re-read it! I don't want the post ID of the current post, I want to use the value from a custom meta key to replace the slug of the post type. I cannot change my permalink structure like you suggest.

Comment: How do I replace the static 'my-friendly-url' with the meta I want to use? I've tried this exact thing but removing the 'my-friendly-url', but that resulted in the page being able to be accessed from any slug, which is not what I want.

Comment: $permalink = home_url( $post->post_name. $meta . "/" ); $meta will be your meta field.

Comment: The post_type_link function is fine, an I have that working. It's the rule rewrite that doesn't work properly, as if I take out the my-friendly-url part of the rule, it means I can get to the page using /anything-i-want-here/postname ... and all the pages are valid

Comment: Do you understand what I mean? I think because the regex rule is now saying 'match anything in the URL at all', this allowsany slug to be used. Do you think I would need something static at the start of the URL to match these rules?

Comment: it's just an example snippet. You need to make your own permalink structure like and I am not getting what you want.

Comment: Are you able to come up with a new regex rule that allows me to do what I want? I have explained it in my question, but am happy to start a discussion to explain more?